# Definir chave estrangeira entre tabelas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Preciso fazer um banco de dados MySQL, `Escola`, com as entidades `aluno`, `professor` e `disciplina`, ligadas através da chave estrangeira.

Fiz meu *script*, mas está dando erro. Vocês poderiam me ajudar? Segue o que fiz:

```
CREATE DATABASE ESCOLA
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET uft8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
use escola;

CREATE TABLE professor(
  nome varchar(50) not null ,
  idade int(2) ,
  salario float(4,2) ,
  cod_prof int(10) not null,
  primary key cod_prof
)CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE aluno(
  nome varchar(50) not null,
  id int(10) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cod_aluno int(10) not null,
  cod_dis int(10) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_aluno)
  CONSTRAINT cod_dis FOREIGN KEY (cod_dis) REFERENCES disciplina(cod_dis)
)CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE disciplina(
  nome varchar(50) not null,
  carga_horaria char(2) ,
  cod_prof int(10) not null,
  cod_dis int(10) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (cod_prof) REFERENCES professor(cod_prof)
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_dis)
)CHARSET=utf8
```

---

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')CHARSET=utf8' at line 7

Comment: Faltou colocar o erro...

Comment: Creio que não tem este = em CHARSET=utf8. Mas você já não definiu para todo o banco?

Comment: Eu to começando.. vi em uns vídeos da internet que com esse códigos posso colocar acentuação nas palavras.

Comment: aluno faz referência a disciplina , criada depois, devecser isto.